# How I can decompose $\ln(3f(x)+2g(y))$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm trying to simplify this equation:

$$\ln(3f(x)+2g(y))$$

where $f$ is a function like $f=2x$ and $g$ is another function like $g=x²$

Can I rewrite this equation?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: In a word, no: there is no simple rule for $ \ \log( x \ ± \ y ) \ $ .  For your example, what _can_ be done is to write $ \ \log (6x + 2x^2) \ = \ \log x \ + \ \log (6 + 2x ) \ $ .

Comment: Try this : $log_2(8+8) \ne log_2(8) + log_2(8)$

Comment: $\ln(3\cdot f(x) +2\cdot g(x))=\ln(3\cdot 2x +2\cdot x^2)=\ln(2x^2+6x)$

Comment: does $f=g'$? or is this a happy coincidence in the examples you chose?

Comment: @zz20s it's not coincidence this details is part of the problem... up vote for notice that!

Comment: The other thing you can do is to "factor" the 2 to write $ \ \log 2 \ + \ \log x \ + \ \log(3 + x) \ . $ I don't think having $ \log (3f \ + \ 2f') \ $ in general improves the situation any...

Comment: If $b>a>0$, then $\ln(a+b)=\ln(a)+2\ln(\sec\arctan\sqrt\frac b a)$

Comment: $sec arctan$ what's this function? thanks for the attention

Comment: @MATHEMATIKER How in the world did you derive that?!

Comment: @AlvaroJoao $\sec(\arctan(x))$ is the secant function of the inverse tangent, or arc-tangent, which are trigonometric functions.

Comment: @SimpleArt Take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709597/derive-logab-loga-2-log-left-cos-left-arctan-left-sqrt-fracba-r?lq=1) :-)

Comment: @MATHEMATIKER Funny link, its actually my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ln(6x+2x^2)=\ln(2x(3+x))=\ln(2x)+\ln(3+x)$$

Apparently, according to MATHEMATIKER,

$$\ln(2x)+\ln(3+x)=\ln(2)+\ln(x)+\ln(3)-2\ln\left(\cos\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{3}}\right)\right)\right)$$

$$=\ln(6)+\ln(x)-2\ln\left(\cos\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{3}}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the attention!!!!

Comment: @AlvaroJoao Your welcome.